# Distributed tracing with golang http.PostForm

Tags: go, microservices, trace, opentracing, distributed-tracing

In my project, I try to implement distributed tracing using `opentracing`.

My microservice has following structure.

```
-- API-Gateway
       |_ User-Service
       |_ Notification
```

In my API-gateway, I start and in API gateway, I use a to a function to start tracing, code is taken from [Setting up your tracer](https://opentracing.io/guides/golang/quick-start/)

in `main()`:

```
gatewayTracer := &apiTracer{tracer: startTracing("API Gateway")}

http.HandleFunc("/getemail", gatewayTracer.validatemail)

func (apitracer apiTracer) validatemail(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    validateEmailSpan := apitracer.tracer.StartSpan("Validate Email")
}
```

I call to my User-service from `validateemail()` using `http.PostForm()`.

`_, err := http.PostForm("http://user:7071/checkemail", url.Values{"uuid": {uuid}, "email": {email}})`

Here `uuid` is for separate task, not for tracing.
I can not post this `Span` to the next service using `PostForm()`.

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done from `PostForm`. You would need to use `http.NewRequest` to create the POST request, `Inject` the span in headers and use `Client.Do` to send the request.