# Opentracing span failed with golang microservice

Tags: go, microservices, opentracing, distributed-tracing

This question is directly related to following questions. None of them solved this issue :

[Distributed tracing with golang http.PostForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58672447/distributed-tracing-with-golang-http-postform)

[POST data faild using http.NewRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58696512/post-data-faild-using-http-newrequest)

[How to pass opentracing data using json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58740621/how-to-pass-opentracing-data-using-json)

[SpanContext not found in Extract carrier in microservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58861152/spancontext-not-found-in-extract-carrier-in-microservice)

This is my current cinfigurations.

In First microservice (API-Gateway) I have following codes :

```
func startTracing(service string) (opentracing.Tracer, io.Closer) {
    cfg := &config.Configuration{
        Sampler: &config.SamplerConfig{
            Type:  "const",
            Param: 1,
        },
        Reporter: &config.ReporterConfig{
            LogSpans: true,
        },
    }
    tracer, closer, err := cfg.New(service, config.Logger(jaeger.StdLogger))
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("ERROR: cannot init Jaeger: %v\n", err))
    }
    return tracer, closer
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/getemail", validatemail)
    http.ListenAndServe(":7070", nil)
}

func validatemail(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    gatewayTracer, gatewayTracerClose := startTracing("Validate Email")

    validateEmailSpan := gatewayTracer.StartSpan("Email address checking")

    // Check method
    if req.Method != "POST" {
        log.Panic("Email form data is not Post")

    }

    email := req.FormValue("email") 

    validEmail := regexp.MustCompile(`^[a-z0-9._%+\-]+@[a-z0-9.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$`) // regex to validate email address

    if validEmail.MatchString(email) {
        httpClient := http.Client{}

        form := url.Values{}
        form.Set("email", email)

        userserviceUrl := "http://user:7071/checkemail"

        checkEmailReq, err := http.NewRequest("POST", userserviceUrl, strings.NewReader(form.Encode()))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        ext.SpanKindRPCClient.Set(validateEmailSpan)
        ext.HTTPUrl.Set(validateEmailSpan, userserviceUrl)
        ext.HTTPMethod.Set(validateEmailSpan, "POST")

        validateEmailSpan.Tracer().Inject(
            validateEmailSpan.Context(),
            opentracing.HTTPHeaders,
            opentracing.HTTPHeadersCarrier(req.Header),
        )
        req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

        resp, err := httpClient.Do(checkEmailReq)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Couldnt verify email address user service sends an error : ", err)
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()

    } else {
        log.Println("Wrong email address format")
    }

    defer gatewayTracerClose.Close()
    defer validateEmailSpan.Finish()
}
```

In my second micro service ( User Service)

```
func CheckEmail(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    checkEmailTracer, checkemailtracerClose := startTracing("Registering Service")  // Same startTracing function as API-Gateway

    spanCtx, _ := checkEmailTracer.Extract(opentracing.HTTPHeaders, opentracing.HTTPHeadersCarrier(req.Header))
    span := checkEmailTracer.StartSpan("format", ext.RPCServerOption(spanCtx))

    defer span.Finish()
    req.ParseForm()

    log.Println("Start from context :", spanCtx)

}
```

Here output from **Start from context ** : `nil`

What am I missing here? I am really new for `opentracing`. Here posted code is taken from [opentracing-tutorial - yurishkur](https://github.com/yurishkuro/opentracing-tutorial/tree/master/go).

Comment: comparing your code to the tutorial, there are two things I've noticed. First is that you declare `tracer` and `closer` in the handler (that means for each request), whereas in the tutorial it's declared in the `main` method. Second thing is that `ext.RPCServerOption(spanCtx)` should be used when creating span in the gateway, not your target service.

Comment: @eminlala The problem was, I used handler, if I define `tracer/closer` in `main` how am I supposed to pass to `validatemail()`

Comment: you could try defining a `Ctrl` struct with a `Tracer` property. In `main` create a `Ctrl` object and assign initialized tracer to it's `Tracer` property. Next, you can define `validatemail` as `func (ctrl *Ctrl) validateemail` and you will have the tracer available inside it. You can check this link: https://gobyexample.com/methods

Comment: @eminlala Thanks, but now I have a problem with `Extract` from secondary service side. In sample, they have started a separate tracer there.

Comment: Did you start a separate tracer instance there, because it should be started separately for each service?

Comment: @eminlala yes, I have started a separate tracer as described. And tried to extract.